# getting error "Expected the reducer to be a function."?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am getting error **"Expected the reducer to be a function."**.

I am trying to add `redux` in my project .I create `reducer` but also getting error "Expected the reducer to be a function." .here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/k5Gp2gglx

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {combindReducer} from './reducers/index'

import Hello from './Hello';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
);
const store = createStore(combindReducer,
                         applyMiddleware(thunk)
                         );
render(
  <Provider store ={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

**combine reducer**

```
import {combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {first_redux} from './topstories';

const combindReducer = combineReducers({
    item: first_redux
})

export default combindReducer;
```

**topstories**

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_ITEM':
            return [
                ...state,
                action.payload
            ];
        case 'DELETE_ITEM':
            const index = state.indexOf(action.payload);
            if (index === -1) {
                return state;
            }
            return state.slice(0, index).concat(state.slice(index + 1));
        case 'UPDATE_ITEM':
            let newList = state.slice()
            newList.splice(action.payload.index, 1, action.payload.item)
            return newList;
        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `combindReducer`?

Comment: Yup, going to need to see the `combinedReducer ` please.

Comment: Is combind a typo? maybe you're not actually importing your reducer.

Comment: wait I am positing

Comment: whole code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/k5Gp2gglx

Comment: did you get any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you're using default exports (not named exports), the import statements for your reducers should not have curly braces:

```
import combindReducer from './reducers/index';
```

and

```
import first_redux from './topstories';
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/L8RE3X5D4